# PrintWriter print vs println

Tags: java, sockets, printing, printwriter

I got a server waiting for messages and a client sending him messages, when using

```
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(lpSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
    String msg;
    BufferedReader userIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    while ((msg = userIn.readLine()) != null)
        out.print(msg + (char) 10);
```

nothing happens, meaning the server just keep waiting for a message that never arrive. When I change the `out.print` to `out.println` it works.

I would like to know why

Comment: Data buffering/flushing.

Comment: It's more readable to use `'\n'` rather than `(char) 10`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, `PrintWriter` calls `flush` in `println`, whereas it doesn't do this in `print`. You can fix this by adding `out.flush()` after your `out.print` call